# Cannot find any fix for Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

i've been trying to figure out how to send push notifications especifically from when firestore database listens to an update to its documents fields. I was following a tutorial from the from the community, i've been trying to get it working, but apparently whatever i do i receive the error described above in the title. Everytime i try to run my app i get the following errors:

```
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Publio\Desktop\Firestore Notification\push\platforms\android\phonegap-plugin-push\pts-push.gradle' line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"
```

I've been looking everywhere to fix this issue and apparently nothing seems to work! I am clueless on how to proceed, i really need some help with this, because i've been stuck in it for a long time now...

In order to describe a little better my issue here's the list of plugins i am currently using:

```
    > cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3 "PushPlugin"
```

Please help me!

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682658/google-login-fcm-together-in-an-ionic-2-project/51682999#51682999

Comment: doesn't work, im not using FCMPlugin

Answer (score 2):

Change following code in **project.properties** from:

Path : platform/android/project.properties

> cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location+

into

> cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2